# To use "test" as an adjectival noun, is the proper form "test" or "testing"?

Tags: nouns, adjectives, parts-of-speech

When I write a document, I am confused when to use **test** or **testing** in my document. For example, which one makes a better statement below?

*A test engineer* vs *A testing engineer*

*software test tool* vs *software testing tool*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Oxford English Dictionary](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/199753) defines the adjective:

> **testing, *adj*.**  That tests or puts to the test or proof.

`Test`, however, is either a noun or a verb. So in your first case, a `test engineer` uses the noun form, and translates to "one who engineers tests". A `testing engineer`, however, means "an engineer who is performing a test" or "an engineer who is performing a test on something".

Similarly, a `software test tool` is "a tool to work with software tests" while a `software testing tool` is "a tool used to carry out tests on software" or "a tool consisting of software that is designed to perform tests".

Comment: A *test engineer* is an engineer who performs tests.  A *testing engineer* would generally be someone who tests one's patience.

Comment: While I agree with the second point as a synonym to my suggestion, I can't say the same for the first. A _mechatronics engineer_ is an engineer who deals with the concepts of mechatronics. A _chemical engineer_ deals with the concepts of chemistry. _Mechatronics_ is a noun while _chemical_ is an adjective, so there seems to be grammatical inconsistency in the phrase across disciplines. However, _testing_ describes the enactment of the verb _test_ and testing one's patience is an example which is syntactically equivalent to testing one's software. A _test engineer_ creates tests.

Comment: I was not referring to specific grammatical rules but rather to what a native speaker in the engineering field would understand if you said *I work with a test engineer* or *I work with a testing engineer*.  *Test engineer* is a term that refers to an engineer who performs/creates tests.  *Testing engineer* is not.

Comment: Yeah, fair enough. In common usage you'd just use _test engineer_ to cover both meanings, but I was just trying to explain the grammatical difference.

Comment: I guess it boils down to the fact _test_ is a noun adjunct (a.k.a. adjectival noun) whereas _testing_ is only ever an adjective, so in answer to the question, and in line with the discussion here, _test_ is the preferred choice in this case.

Answer (score 4):

I know that there is

> a hardware or software test engineer

who determines how to create a process that would test a product. Also,

> software testing tools

is correct, because your term is about “testing a software” (If I got you right).